# DB2 Online Restore but Without Roll Forward?

Tags: db2, backup, restore

I read a lot of documentations for db2 restore but I could not find how to perform online restore from the last database backup but without roll forwarding of logs?

I will appreciate command example.

On example my last online backup is made 1st february. I want to do ONLINE RESTORE of that backup but without logs after 1st February (similar with offline restore option WITHOUT ROLL FORWARD).

I am using db2 9.7

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

The database backup contains a snapshot of the tablespaces, and they may not be in stable state. Roll-forward is always required (unless you want to take insane risks by forcing DB2 to start using potentially corrupt data) to reach the nearest stable state.

If you are asking your question because you want manageable database backup dumps without having to worry about shipping logs etc, use the `INCLUDE LOGS` option when taking the backup. It will include in the backup file the minimum set of transaction logs that would be required for reaching stable state. When restoring you could then use the `LOGS` to extract them and then `ROLLFORWARD DATABASE` for the required typical 0-x seconds (depending on your database transactions).

A lazy dba would probably just use the `RECOVER DB SAMPLE TO  2013-02-01-00.00.00` and allow the DB2 to worry about all the details. It will automatically fetch the required database backup and transaction files (even from the backup tapes etc if you set them up correctly), and do everything for you - as long as you don't attempt to manually manage them.